# C# Get URI Segments by name

Tags: c#, api

Is there any way to get the Segment of a URI using its name?

For example if I have the template:

```
http://myapi.com/v1/players/{country}
```

How could I extract the value of `{country}` once it has been matched using `UriTemplateMatch`?

I have [read the docs for the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments(v=vs.110).aspx) and currently use this approach

```
string country = requestedUri.Segments[3];
```

This method is fine for static URI's, but as soon as paths change it can be a lot of hassle to go back and make changes.

Comment: `UriTemplateMatch` docs give a good sample of how it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retrieve the bound variables using the `BoundVariables` property of the `UriTemplateMatch`

You have a good example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplatematch.requesturi(v=vs.110).aspx)

... so basically if we have

`UriTemplateMatch results`

after matching you can simply call

`results.BoundVariables["country"];`

to get what you are looking for. 
Unless I am missing the problem here, and for some reason you don't want to keep the UriTemplateMatch object.